# Retrieve UTC times added during daylight savings

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have a table where I a user can store and event. The start time of the event is stored in a column, the column field is `time`. During daylight savings, where I am, the offset in hours is `-5` so if the user stores an event that starts at `12:00pm` it will be stored in the database as `17:00:00`. If the user were to create an event with the exact same starting time when it isn't daylight savings the timezone offset would be `-4` and it would be stored in the database as `16:00:00`.

If a user selects all of the events starting at 12:00pm and it's daylight savings I will get the users timezone offset using javascript (in this case its -5) and create the query accordingly `WHERE startTime > 17:00:00`. The problem is all of the events that were created when it wasn't daylight savings have a start time of `16:00:00` because the offset was `-4` and not `-5` so they will not be selected.

Any solutions to this problem? Is my method of storing the startTime of the event completely wrong?

Comment: Where are you doing the UTC conversion?

Comment: In php just before the event is added.

Comment: any particular reason you dont just use `utc_timestamp()` as the value to insert?

Comment: note how `alert(new Date(2000,0,1,0,0,0).toISOString())` shows the local date. so, if you construct a Date like that, using corrected values from the server (just the utc, ignoring dst), then the times should be right regardless of what time of the year it was then or is now.

Comment: The problem is that they are at different UTC times, but the same local time. So store them using local time, or have a second column for the offset applicable at the time they're created so you can adjust to local time, kind of "*where UTC+offset = 17:00*" but in valid SQL of course.

Comment: @pala_—that doesn't help.

Comment: @dandavis—yeah, but the query is saying 17:00 when the time has been stored as 16:00 'cos it was daylight saving at the time.

Comment: ah hang on, future dated events. i should read better. and you should be storing all events using a common timezone, and retrieve them by applying the user timezone to the query

Comment: @RobG: can the DB not convert on the way out like JS converts on the way in? i would be expecting to get utc stamps from the server, or timezone-specific date strings...

Comment: @dandavis—it can be done for a single date by adjusting the time in the query for the applicable offset, but what about a time on a range of dates that start and end either side of a DST boundary?

Comment: i think the quickest workaround would be to over-query the extra hour and filter client-side using UTC-compensated dates (js can adjust DST based on the calendar). presuming you have real dates in the full item coming in the response. like making the same mistake twice to cancel out both.

Comment: I think I will go with @RobG but it feels wrong... Is there a more proper way you would do this?

Comment: @RobG nvm your method wont work because if the time is `02:00:00` and   the and your are 4 hours back (offset of -4) using your method you will get `-02:00:00` not `22:00:00` unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `DATE` and a `TIME` value, and you know the geographic timezone used when you recorded these dates and times, you can use [`CONVERT_TZ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to retrieve the UTC times from the local time data.

First you use `ADDTIME()` to combine your `DATE` and `TIME` data into a `DATETIME` value.  This gets you 07:00 on May 5.

```
 ADDTIME(DATE('2015-05-01'), TIME('07:00:00'))
```

Then you convert that from your local geographic time to UTC.

```
CONVERT_TZ( ADDTIME(DATE('2015-05-01'), TIME('07:00:00')), 'America/New_York', 'UTC')
```

Try this MySQL statement, and you'll see that `America/New_York` conversion handles the daylight savings time correctly.

```
select CONVERT_TZ( ADDTIME(DATE('2015-05-01'), TIME('07:00:00')), 'America/New_York', 'UTC'),
       CONVERT_TZ( ADDTIME(DATE('2015-01-01'), TIME('07:00:00')), 'America/New_York', 'UTC')
```

This works for all sorts of time zones. See, for example, [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/timezone.html), for a list.

If you're doing a database design from scratch, it's smart to record all times in the same time zone. In fact, set up your servers to run in UTC, not local time. The easy way to do this is to use MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` data type: it always records times internally in UTC. It converts from local time when recording, and back to local time when retrieving. It uses the connection's time zone setting to do this.

**Edit**

Suppose you have an event table with user_id, evdate, evtime, and description columns.  Suppose also you have a user table with user_id and user_tz columns.  Then you can find the events between two dates, utc, with a query like this.

```
  SELECT u.user_name, e.description, 
         CONVERT_TZ( ADDTIME(e.evdate, e.evtime), u.user_tz, 'UTC') start
    FROM event.e
    JOIN user.u ON e.user_id = u.user_id
   WHERE CONVERT_TZ( ADDTIME(e.evdate, e.evtime), u.user_tz, 'UTC') >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00'
```

This assume that each user has an assigned time zone, and that all the dates and times for the user are stored in that user's assigned time zone.

Comment: Thanks, so with your answer as long as I store the date of the event and timezone name I don't have to convert the time when I add it to the database, right?